# CRUD Stored procedure for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, crud, procedure

I have a oracle database and would like an easy way to generate stored procedure for crud (Create,Retrieve,Update,Delete). I've been searching the internet but couldn't find any proper tool.

Comment: I reviewed this http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator but the structure of the schema I was working with did not lend itself to this tool.

Comment: CRUD stored procedures are the wrong way to design how you interact with the database, IMHO. Instead, you should aim to put the business logic into the stored procs (ie. "Add customer", "add order", "Mark order as dispatched" etc). It's all very well designing your system as if only one app is going to talk to the db, but what then if a second one is added? You have to repeat the same logic in both apps if you go the CRUD way.

Comment: (Each related stored proc should then be stored together in a package. Thus any common code can be easily reused.)

Comment: It's easy to write, so you can do it yourself !

Answer (score 6):

Oracle SQL Developer offers this feature. Right click on your table, and choose, Generate Table API

[image: This will create a package with insert, update, and delete procedures]

Comment: I want to create procedure in order to minimize  the number of code lines . Input parameters should be ( data of insertion, table_ of_ insertion, type_of_dml_operation).  The result of this procedure  should be execution of CRUD DML operations.

Comment: You want one procedure to do everything? Wow... I doubt that your code will be as flexible as you anticipate, nor do I expect it will be simple. How will you cope with tables that have lots of columns, with clob datatypes? How will you decide to update columns to null? This sounds even more monumentally insane than your original request sounded *{:-( )

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks body!!